# C opening a file and reading

Tags: c, io

I have the following code

```
int open(char* name) {

FILE *stream = fopen(name, "r");

fscanf(stream,"%d", &n);

    i = 0;

    while(i < n) {
        fscanf(stream, "%s %d\n", stringArr[i], &val);

        intArr[i] = val + counter + 1;

        i++;
    }

    while(fscanf(stream, "%[^\n]\n", outputArr[counter]) == 1) {

        counter++;
    }

    i = 0;
}
```

which works perfectly fine.

I'm new with C and would like to learn more about efficiency etc, so i am wondering is there a better way to write this?

I will explain how the file works and what the method should do

The file looks like

```
2
TREE 4
SIX 1
Welcome, how are you?
This is the beginning of the end.
```

The first number you see, is the number of "important words" Namely `TREE 4, and SIX 1`.

So we first have to read in the number of important words, and then with that we have too put those `words and the values` into a `symbol table` like structure. I am just using two arrays one for the `words` and one for the `values`. That's what the first `while loop` does.

The second while loop, continues on the file to the non-important lines, and reads those to an outputArray.

This has gotten quite long, but my basic question is, is there any way to make this code better?

Thanks!

Comment: should add checks to your code to make sure the functions you're calling are working as expected...especially the call to `fopen` !

Comment: @ChrisTurner - Thank's ill look into that

Comment: If the code works, and you only want a code review, then you should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @mike.feen123 I don't want to shock you but what you presented is a really short sample of C code. I'm sometimes afraid about the number of lines in our productive code (actually C++ but similar issue). But, when I look into the code of other projects (open source) I see that other don't do much better. This is probably because C (as well as C++) is a low level language. Programs in high level languages (e.g. Python, bash script, etc.)  tend to become much shorter. To calm down, I imagine how much longer the code would be when completely written in assembler code...